# Unlikely female heroine, meets floating mages; What was this title?

Tags: story-identification, magic, young-adult

I read a fantasy book as a youth that I cannot for the life if me remember the title to. It's all rather fuzzy except one particular scene and detail. I'll list what I can remember.

It's a female protagonist, I believe of the unlikely hero/questing type. 
There are forest-dwelling creatures abundant in this universe that assume the guise of something comforting or appealing to whoever sees them to lure them to their deaths.

The wizard/mage she encounters doesn't walk on the earth, and instead floats just above the ground, leaving no footprints. 
The mage is the romantic interest. 
There is a scene between the two where she believes him to be one of the aforementioned creatures because he lacks footprints.

I know it's not much to go on, but I've searched high and low to no avail. It's doing my head in trying to remember. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would it be one of Mercedes Lackey's novels? She often writes female protagonists and mages.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 7):

[*The Two Princesses of Bamarre*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Two_Princesses_of_Bamarre)!  It was written by [Gail Carson Levine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gail_Carson_Levine). I have been looking for this book for years. I have done random Internet searches to find it and after reading your comment, I finally did! I hope you enjoy it as much as I'm going to. Gosh I've missed this book!

Comment: Welcome to the site Amber!